# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need your help. I'm trying to get API data through redux. I have everything I need: action_types, action_creators, reducer. When I try to draw data, I get an error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`.What is my mistake? Thank you very much. Here is my code

cartoons.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {cartoons_are_loaded} from "../redux/action_creators";

export let Cartoons = () => {

let dispatch = useDispatch();
let cartoons = useSelector(({cartoon_reducer: {cartoons}}) => cartoons);

let fetchCartoons = async () => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('https://api.sampleapis.com/cartoons/cartoons2D');
        let json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
        dispatch(cartoons_are_loaded(json.data))
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
   if (!cartoons.length){
       fetchCartoons();
   }
},[])

return (<div>
    {cartoons.map(el => <div key={el.id}>{el.title}</div>)}
        </div>)
}
```

reducers.js

```
import {CARTOONS_ARE_LOADED} from "./action_types";

let initialState = {
cartoons: []
}

let cartoon_reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case CARTOONS_ARE_LOADED: {
        return {
            ...state,
            cartoons: action.payload
        }
    }

    default:
        return state;
}
}
export default cartoon_reducer;
```

action_types.js

```
let CARTOONS_ARE_LOADED = 'CARTOONS_ARE_LOADED';
let DELETE_FAVOURITE_MOVIE = 'DELETE_FAVOURITE_MOVIE';
let ADD_FAVOURITE_CARTOON = 'ADD_FAVOURITE_MOVIE';
export {
CARTOONS_ARE_LOADED,
ADD_FAVOURITE_CARTOON,
DELETE_FAVOURITE_MOVIE
}
```

action_creators.js

```
import {
CARTOONS_ARE_LOADED,
} from "./action_types";
let cartoons_are_loaded = (payload) => ({type : CARTOONS_ARE_LOADED, payload});
export {
cartoons_are_loaded
}
```

all_reducers.js

```
import cartoon_reducer from "./reducers";
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
export let root_reducer = combineReducers({
cartoon_reducer
})
```

Comment: For the `CARTOONS_ARE_LOADED` case what is the `action.payload` value? It seems you are not maintaining the state invariant of an array.

Comment: I suggest using the browser developer tools to debug your code. You should install the React Dev tools and Redux dev tools.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Ok i will install. I have one more question.I make such requests 10 times. But I try to draw 9 components, the data are not drawn, although I do everything with the same example. Question, is there any restriction in query execution?

Comment: @Ronald You should post a new question by clicking the button at the top right of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The JSON response is ***already*** an array.

```
let json = await response.json();
```

> ```
> // 20210915235745
> // https://api.sampleapis.com/cartoons/cartoons2D
>
> [
>   {
>     "title": "Spongebob Squarepants",
>     "year": 1999,
>     "creator": [
>       "Stephen Hillenburg"
>     ],
>     "rating": "TV-Y",
>     "genre": [
>       "Comedy",
>       "Family"
>     ],
>     "runtime_in_minutes": 23,
>     "episodes": 272,
>     "image": "https://nick.mtvnimages.com/uri/mgid:arc:content:nick.com:9cd2df6e-63c7-43da-8bde-8d77af9169c7?quality=0.7",
>     "id": 1
>   },
>   ...
>   {
>     "title": "The New Adventures of Winnie the Pooh",
>     "year": 1988,
>     "creator": [
>       "Karl Geurs",
>       "Terence Harrison",
>       "Ken Kessel"
>     ],
>     "rating": "TV-Y",
>     "genre": [
>       "Adventure",
>       "Comedy"
>     ],
>     "runtime_in_minutes": 30,
>     "episodes": 50,
>     "image": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjFkZDkwYjktMmZkNi00ZTVkLWI5ZmItZWI2MmI1NjQ1Y2U0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyOTg4MDk3MTQ@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,666,1000_AL_.jpg",
>     "id": 23
>   }
> ]
> ```

There is no `data` property, or in other words, `json.data` is undefined, and thus, not mappable.

## Solution

Just dispatch the action with the `json` JSON data value:

```
dispatch(cartoons_are_loaded(json))
```

Full code:

```
const fetchCartoons = async () => {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('https://api.sampleapis.com/cartoons/cartoons2D');
    let json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    dispatch(cartoons_are_loaded(json)) // <-- pass just `json`
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Here's an example codesandbox using local state instead of redux:

[image: Edit cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-map]